# How to solve HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443) when I use poetry install

Tags: python, python-poetry, dvc

I am getting this error when I use poetry install in different repos of my organization (using a Mac):

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/dvc/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

I have tried uninstalling and installing python e pyenv, updating pip and installing certifi.

I think the problem has to do with dvc, because I receive a similar error when I try to use dvc get to download a pickle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip install fails with "connection error: \[SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED\] certificate verify failed (\_ssl.c:598)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)